# Which method is better?

Tags: c#

I am using an import to open a connected physical hard-drive:

```
var sfh = Imports.CreateFile(Path, Imports.FileAccess.GenericAll, Imports.FileShare.None, IntPtr.Zero, Imports.CreationDisposition.OpenExisting, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
if (sfh.IsInvalid)
{
    Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(Marshal.GetHRForLastWin32Error());
    return;
}
Geometry = Imports.GetGeometry(sfh);
var fs = new FileStream(sfh, FileAccess.ReadWrite, (int)Geometry.BytesPerSector, false);
```

That works fine, but instead of using FileStream, I was wondering if this would be a more efficient way to read bytes from the drive: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365467%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: Underneath the covers, the framework is almost certainly calling the win32 ReadFile function you linked, and doing so efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

Is speed and/or efficiency that important for you ?? because the difference is probably minor in this case...

It seems like the link you gave uses a WinAPI method. I would avoid using these were you don't necessarily have to since the .net GarbageCollector doesn't play well with Native resources, and you might suffer from memory leaks if you don't handle these correctly...

Comment: More like reading the bytes properly. With the FileStream, I have to make sure it reads the right bytes and such because they are sector aligned. I want to know if this will eliminate any potential issues with sectors.

I do this to go to a position

                var cnt = Position % Geometry.BytesPerSector != 0 ? Geometry.BytesPerSector : 0x200;
                if (cnt != 0)
                {
                    EIO.SetPosition(Position - cnt);
                    EIO.Reader.ReadBytes((int) cnt);
                    return;
                }
                EIO.SetPosition(Position);

Comment: Ah, that didn't come out right. :x

http://pastie.org/private/et0oy1ggugqk5ktx3wg